# verificationTokens.generate method for Google Business Profiles throws 404

Tags: php, google-api-client, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

Calling POST method on `https://mybusinessverifications.googleapis.com/v1/verificationTokens:generate` with correct `Location` object in request body gets me:

```
Client error:
POST https://mybusinessverifications.googleapis.com/v1/verificationTokens:generate
resulted in a 404 Not Found response: 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang=en> <meta charset=utf-8> <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, w (truncated...)
```

This URL is correct per:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/verifications/rest/v1/verificationTokens/generate

Code (just repeating other requests that work with a different endpoint):

```
$account = $this->getAccounts('XXXX');
$filter = [];
$filter['store_code'] = 'YYY';
$locations = $this->getLocations($account, $filter);
$location=$locations[0];
$response = $client->authorize()->post('https://mybusinessverifications.googleapis.com/v1/verificationTokens:generate', ['location' => $location]);
dd($response);
```

Only errors listed in the docs are:
`Throws PERMISSION_DENIED if the caller is not a vetted partner account. Throws FAILED_PRECONDITION if the caller's VettedStatus is INVALID.`

What's going on? Anybody with some experience using this endpoint?

Comment: There is no actual code in your question. Do you have some? Is it PHP code? Please show us how you're executing the POST method by editing your question.

Comment: Completely off-topic: I like your [Cycling Coalition](https://cyklokoalicia.sk/en/).

Comment: Thanks! I have added the sample code, although I don't think that's going to help much - there are too many opaque functions in between. The issue seems to be with the URL itself or maybe some pre-condition such as being a "vetted partner". I have similar code working with other endpoints, so there should not be any issue other than the actual URL ether incorrect or the client authorization not meeting some conditions (although here the doc state that a different error should be thrown).

Comment: I agree, that code doesn't really help. Sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: Have you tried URL-encoding that colon `:` in the URL path, as `%3A`?

Comment: URL encoding is not needed for this particular method. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information from Google Business Profiles Support:

> I have confirmed with our internal team that this method has been
> removed.
>
> Sincerely, Shalini
>
> The Google Business Profile API team

Answer (score 1):

Since the reference seemingly has become unavailable (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/verifications/rest/v1/verificationTokens/generate), it's possible it was public by mistake and should only have been available to certain vetted partners that were given extended access to the reference in the first place. If you are a vetted partner, reaching out to your partner manager or the GBP API support might help to get access to the reference and yield responses from the API.